# Is it possible to transfer exiting Windows installation to Mac Boot Camp partition?

Tags: windows-7, boot-camp, transfer

Is there a hack that allows us to transfer an existing Windows 7 installation to a Boot Camp partition on a Mac?

If there is, does it have any side effects, or shortcomings like being less efficient, etc.?

Comment: If it's running on Intel CPU, it *could* potentially work. But I'd sooner do something like `disk2vhd` (from SysInternals) and run the Windows machine virtualised.

Answer (score 0):

What sort of computer is Windows installed on? There will almost certainly be driver issues, but they may be overcome-able. A bigger problem will be the secret sauce Apple uses to make Boot Camp work.

Possible solution: install a fresh Windows 7 of a matching flavor (32 vs. 64 bit), then overwrite its partition with your existing install. This way you can use a more-typical Windows-migration solution, one that someone who knows more about Windows than I can supply.

Comment: This is going to be ugly, whatever you do.

Comment: Hey, I have a Macbook Air, and my Windows is on a Toshiba Machine.

Comment: Thanks for the comments guys. I think I've decided to install a fresh copy and transfer my documents and settings by the easy transfer wizard. The only downfall is, that I have to install all my applications again.

Comment: That's probably the least troublesome solution.